# SQL - Insert Into Select query with lookup of value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Morning all, I need some help please.

I have a database with several tables. I'm trying to write an INSERT INTO and SELECT query that copies all values from one Table (TableA) into another Table (TableD) but substitutes one value with a value it looks up in another table (Table B).

Table A with various fields including TableBRef

Table B includes various fields starting with TableBRef and also includes a field TableCRef

I want to copy all of TableA into Table D but replace The TableBRef with the TableCRef ie I know TableBRef, I need to search for it in TableB and return the associated value from the TableCRef field.

```
INSERT INTO TableD
                      (DRef, CRef, DData1, DData2)
SELECT     TableA.ARef, TableB.CRef, TableA.AData1, TableA.AData2
FROM         TableD AS TableD_1 CROSS JOIN
                      TableC CROSS JOIN
                      TableA INNER JOIN
                      TableB ON TableA.BRef = TableB.BRef
```

Sorry, I thought that calling them generic table names may help but it's actually a little confusing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how you relate each table but see if this query will work for you

```
INSERT INTO TableD
           (DRef, CRef, DData1, DData2)
SELECT     a.ARef, c.CRef, a.AData1, a.AData2
from        tableA a
            left outer join tableB b on a.ARef = b.ARef
            inner join tableC c on b.CRef = c.CRef
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the left outer join to a.BRef = b.BRef to match my relationships and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Good for you! since i didn't know how to relate them. But congrats!